# SO dates calculation and formatting

Tags: php, date

What script SO uses for dates displaying? Because it seems to be pretty nice formatting and logical showing.

Comment: You can get a clue by compiling a list of examples, observing a pattern, then re-implementing it yourself. Easy!

Comment: Why was this question migrated? It's a programming question using SO as an example

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what StackOverflow use. But one of the most common timestamp representaion is the one done by twitter which displays timestamp as `a moment ago`, `30 seconds ago`, `x minutes ago`, `yesterday`, `10:30 PM Apr 12, 2010` etc. And it updates the timestamp every five seconds *without hitting the server*.

If you are interested you may look into [John Resig's Pretty Date JS API](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/). It's just awesome. Works with/without JQuery.

We tweaked it a bit to exactly match Twitter pattern. And it *is* awesome.

---

The website mentioned gives good example, but if you *so* want a working version, put the following script in address bar of any web-page. (you may want to tweak parameters passed to `prettyDate` function

```
  javascript:var i,s,ss=['http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js'];for(i=0;i!=ss.length;i++){s=document.createElement('script');s.src=ss[i];document.body.appendChild(s);}alert("PrettyDate: "+(prettyDate("2011-03-13T03:24:17Z")?prettyDate("2011-03-13T03:24:17Z"):"03:24 AM Mar 13, 2011"));
```

Comment: I like how it's limited to the past month and cannot do dates beyond that, or any future dates. (I prefer [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com).)

Comment: @Tomalak it is not meant to work for future date. Because usually you map an event that _has_ passed. But, tweaking the code is dead simple. We tweaked it quite a bit. Also, we removed the feature of last month, becasue after 2 - 3 weeks people would want to see exact timestamp. But as I said, just open the JS code, it's simple to adopt to your use case.

Comment: Would be better if it weren't so pointlessly limited out of the box. I don't want some developer telling me what my "usual" use case is... and getting it wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah http://timeago.yarp.com/ is also good one for some reasons it did not fit into our needs at that time.

Comment: @Doolkin no, after a month it starts returning undefined where you'll print exact timestamp.

Comment: @Nishant - i'm trying to use it, but i'm really confused from this script and the demo...can you show me some simple example how i should use it?

Comment: @Doolkin did you try the javascript I have updated in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's based on the answers to [this question on Stack Overflow asked by Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) - most of the answers are in c# but there is a PHP implementation too